# How to find the correct path for a external javascript file when using servlets?

Tags: javascript, servlets

I'm not familiar with java servlets and I'm using the servlet to write the HTML document like so:

```
out.println(
"<HTML>\n" +
"<HEAD><TITLE></TITLE></HEAD>\n" +
"<BODY>\n" +
"<H1>"+ "</H1>\n" +
"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"testME.js\"></script></BODY></HTML>")
```

But the script testME.js does not run, so I'm guessing I need to give it the correct path.  I just don't know what the path would be if the testME.js file is in the WebContent folder.   The main reason I am using an external script is so I can avoid using all the quotations and "\n" as I am writing the javascript.  If anyone one knows of a better way to avoid this that would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add Forward Slash (/).

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/testME.js\">
```